# Mudblazor Input Capture

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I want to use the native android camera to upload a picture to my webservice. I do this by using:

```
<input id="imageFileInput"
       type="file"
       accept="image/*"
       capture="environment" />
```

I searched the mudblazor docs and did not found a way to achieve this behavior using mudblazor components. According to [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture):

```
The capture attribute is supported on the file input type.
```

Anyone has an idea how to do this? Did I miss something?